# Bringing application to foreground on shake in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios5, shake, background-foreground

The application is running in background. I want that when someone shakes IPhone the application should come to foreground from background.
Is there any way to do this programmatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No, this caanot happen. You dont have any control when your app is in BG.

Comment: I dont need any control but the application should just open on shake

Comment: In my answer 'control' means not any UI interaction control(Button/label/textField). It means your code will not interact with iOS when it is in background. You can use this feature only when your app is in foreground.

Comment: can we play song when app is in background by shaking?